# Split a single drf viewset class into multiple classes?

Tags: django-rest-framework, organization, django-rest-viewsets

Right now I have a large viewset class (~1300 lines). The reason for this is, I had to add a lot of `@action` decorators to acheive my goal. But I can feel that this is taking a lot of my time in debugging and navigating the code. I want to know if there's a way to break this class into multiple files.

I don't know how to split a single into multiple classes and not sure if this is even possible.